# getting the id value of current url in asp.net mvc 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

i am using a actionlink in master page of user module.i want to pass the eventid of the current url(in all views) to the actionlink as a route value.But i use the following code,

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Create Account", "UserRegistration",
      new { eventid = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] })%>
```

But it doesnot retrieve the id fom the url.

my url is in following formate,

http://localhost:12905/User/User/Order?eventID=2

here eventID=2 is common for all views.So i want to send this eventID to the actionlink as route value.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be "eventId" instead of "id" in the ActionLink:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(... ViewContext.RouteData.Values["eventId"] })%>
```

Comment: thanks for replying M4N.Bit i tried like given.but it displays the following error,

Comment: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'eventid' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult UserRegistration(Int32)' in 'Stalbans.Areas.User.Controllers.UserController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters